# Core data: NSFetchedResultsController with objects are in a relationship

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two entities `CIDMPost` and `CIDMUser`. CIDMPost has a `one-to-many` relationship with CIDMUser named `invitees`.
Now I have an instance of `CIDMPost` lets say `postObject` from where I can easily get the invitees by writing `postObject.invitees` which will return `NSSet`.

Now my requirement is I want those invitees (postObject.invitees) as `NSFetchedResultsController` to show in a `UITableView` with style `Group`. Also its need to satisfy the below.

1. Grouped by invitationStatus (an attribute of CIDMUser)
2. Order by invitationStatus ASC

> Declaration:

I tried few things to fulfil my requirement but got a crashed and the reason was `Invalid to many relationship`. To know the solution of this crash I posted '[a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402738/application-crash-reason-invalid-to-many-relationship)' an hour ago. But after few conversation with [Daij-Djan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420303/daij-djan) I had come to know that the whole process I was trying is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fetch the users in your fetched results controller and apply the sort descriptors as desired filter by invitation with a predicate. Use the status field as the `sectionNameKeyPath` argument when creating the fetched results controller.

```
NSPredicate(format: "%@ in invitations", post)
```

where `post` is the post object to which you want to display the invitees, and `invitations` is the reverse to-many relationship to the post to which users are invited.

*(Note that I am assuming a user can get invited to more than one post, which seems logical. In your problem statement you mention a one-to-many relationship which it seems to me should thus be many-to-many).*

Comment: Thanks bro. I was actually looking for this. :)